# C++ Ice Slice Divide class to cpp and h

Tags: c++, slice, ice

I'm newbie in programming in Ice and i have a problem. I wrote module in Ice

```
module Demo
{
    exception NoSuchWord{};

    sequence<string> words;
    dictionary<string,words> myDictionary;

    interface Translator
    {
        words translate(string s) throws NoSuchWord;
    }
}
```

In Server.cpp I implemented that interface Translator:

```
class TranslatorI : public Translator
{
public:
    virtual words translate(const string& s, const Ice::Current&);
};


words TranslatorI::translate(const string& s, const Ice::Current&)
{
    words rewords = dictionary[s];
    if(rewords.size() == 0){
        throw NoSuchWord();
    }
    return rewords;
}
```

in main(Server.cpp) i created InterfaceI :

```
Ice::ObjectPtr object = new TranslatorI;
```

If i have class TranslatorIand implementation traslator in one class Server.cpp its works, but when i divide it to Translate.h(class TranslatorI) and Translate.cpp(implementation TranslatorI) then i have problem like reference vtable TranslatorI

Comment: Hi, can you post the actual compiler error, and provide the version of Ice and C++ compiler you are using.

Comment: Version Ice 3.7.1, GCC 5.4.0
Error: https://imgur.com/a/ON0yutr
I changed virtual method to virtual words translate(const string & s, const ICE::Current&) = 0; and now i cant create InterfaceI,  I'm going in the right direction?

Comment: Seems like you are not linking with TranslatorI.o

Comment: i try c++ -o Translator.o  Translator.h Translator.cpp but still have that same problem undefined reference

Comment: I created makefile and its works! Thank you!